# How do I specify this kind of variable argument tuple with python typing?

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm trying to do this, but I'm not sure how to specify the type signature:

```
def initialize_signals(
        self,
        command: InitializeCommand,
        initializers: Iterable[Union[
            Tuple[SignalNode],
            Tuple[SignalNode, Any, ...]
                  ]]):
    for x, *args in initializers:
        potential_update = command.create_potential_update(x, *args)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there currently isn't an annotation which can represent the addition of a fixed-length tuple with a variable length tuple.

here's some code I used to determine how mypy's inference would handle something like this:

```
from typing import Tuple

x: Tuple[int, ...]
y = ('hi', *x)
z = (*x,)
reveal_type(y)
reveal_type(z)
```

and output:

```
$ mypy t.py
t.py:6: error: Revealed type is 'builtins.tuple[builtins.object*]'
t.py:7: error: Revealed type is 'builtins.tuple[builtins.int*]'
```

despite knowing that it's a variable-length `int` tuple it decays to `object`.

You may want to refactor your code to use `Tuple[SignalNode, Tuple[Any, ...]]` instead

Comment: Thanks!  I know that the refactoring you suggest is more logical.   However, this code is called so much that it feels painful to add `(,)` all over the place.  It does seem that this feature could theoretically (and without breaking anything) be added to python typing.